# Is the DOM reconstructed upon a successful AJAX request that alters the page's HTML?

Tags: html, ajax, dom

Let's say you make an AJAX request that upon success alters some amount of HTML in the page (e.g. adds a table, removes a paragraph's content, etc.). If the DOM is constructed upon the loading of the page and AJAX allows for asynchronous calls that don't alter the display or behavior of the page, then does the browser parse the DOM and add/delete any changes upon successful AJAX requests or is the DOM  completely rebuilt?

Comment: Are you using some specific library like jQuery or just raw `XMLHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

No, DOM is not completely rebuilt or reconstructed. If you want to change something, you need to do that using normal DOM methods.